# spring api gateway doesnt redirect me to spring-cloud-gateway-client url provided by keycloak

Tags: java, spring, microservices, keycloak, gateway

I am following a tutorial in youtube and using Keycloak as Identity Provider, Spring Cloud Gateway as API Gateway and multiple Microservices
My issue is that, spring gateway redirect my `http://localhost:8090/api/product` url to `http://localhost:8090/login` instead of `http://localhost:8090/login/oauth2/code/spring-cloud-gateway-client` url that i set in keycloak server

**api-gateway-service pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**api-gateway-service property file**

```
server.port=8090
spring.application.name=api-gateway

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true


spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/product

eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}-${random.uuid}
spring.security.user.name=aaa
spring.security.user.password=aaa
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#keycloak configuration
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/microservices-realm
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-id=spring-cloud-gateway-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-secret=fe7a2722-2c96-45d7-a9e4-6ee9da224a43
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization-code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8090/login/oauth2/code/spring-cloud-gateway-client

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/microservices-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

**api-gateway-service security config**

```
package com.example.apigatewayservice;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
```

**ApiGatewayServiceApplication**

```
nothing special just main method
```

**keycloack client informations**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILYvF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, in property file in this field
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization-code

i wrote authorization-code instead of authorization_code

what a silly mistake that took me 1 hour

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).